# "Лечить болезнь" или "лечить от болезни"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто можно услышать "простуда лечится так...". Но разве это правильно? Лечить можно человека, а болезнь зачем лечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос понятен. Можно ли "лечить болезнь" в значении "лечить от болезни"?
В словаре Кузнецова такое значение "лечить" признается допустимым.

*ЛЕЧИТЬ, лечу, лечишь; нсв. (св. вылечить и излечить)...
что, от чего. Разг. Принимать меры к прекращению какой-л. болезни. Л. малярию. Л. грипп. Л. от простуды.*

Хотя тут помета "разг." относится к обоим вариантам - лечить болезнь и лечить от болезни, т. е. такие варианты равнонормативны.